# How to refer to an employer that isn't a company

Tags: word-choice, vocabulary

What term may use I refer to a non-business employer? For instance, a babysitter or housekeeper working for a family or single parent.

Comment: They're still employing you, so they're still your employer. And of course the generic "*boss*" still works.

Comment: @DanBron Thanks for your reply. How could you emphasize the fact they are not a company. Is there an adjective for that?

Comment: In legal and political contexts, "not a company" is usually denoted by the phrase "*natural person*", but I don't think that works well in your situation. I'm sure there are better ways to phrase it. (You could of course always fall back on descriptive phrases like "*The family I work for*".)

Comment: Yes, finally I'll use the "self-employed" concept, now whether a baby-sitter is self-employed or has an employer is another debate, but I think I'll keep this. Thanks :-)

Comment: @DanBron Do you think that "individual employer" makes sense in this case?

Comment: Sure, or maybe personal employer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Individual employer* is the common definition for a a person employing their own staff:

[Support for individual employers](http://Support%20for%20individual%20employers) :

> - There are many benefits to employing your own staff to provide care and support in your own home but we also know that being an employer can be daunting and confusing. Skills for Care has a range of resources to help make this process easier to understand and to help you support your personal assistant (PA) with learning and development. We also have information about funding that is available for training for you and your PA.

[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=individual%20employer%2C%20personal%20employer&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cindividual%20employer%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpersonal%20employer%3B%2Cc0): individual employer vs personal employer.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I might use these concepts, but do you think that "individual employer" makes sense in this case?

Comment: Yes, in the case the self-employed person employes their own staff.

Comment: I don't think this is quite right.  OP is asking about what an *employer* is called when that person is not a company.  I take this to mean, for example, if I am a gardener and work for a nice old lady, I would not call that old lady self-employed or a sole proprietor and if I worked full-time for her and only her I wouldn't even call myself self-employed either.